# How to make the method: layoutsubviews that synchronously excute?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I made a sub class **TKButton** of **UIButton** and provided a property **hasUpdate** of type BOOL.

I tried to overwrite its **setHasUpdate** method and initialized the new view which is not configured frame while having red color.

When hasUpdate is Yes, make the hidden = No else Yes.

At last I used setNeedsLayout method. In this method layoutSubvew, tried to change the  new view frame.

If I set hasUpdate = YES , I hope the _badgeView appeared. However,it seems that it does not appear immediately. It might be the setNeedsLayout is asynchronies.

Does anyone has the idea about this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please read and edit your question? It is hard to understand, caused by the many grammatical errors. I cannot tell what the real problem is, I don't think the problem is that the method gets called asynchronously. So far, you can use `@synchronized (self) { /* method implementation */ }` to make it synchronous. Please make your question more clear so we can find the real issue.

Comment: Please also provide code samples and make sure you have read and obey these rules cast in stone: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask